# Specifying coordinates for Inset on a LogPlot

Tags: plotting

If I use `Epilog->Inset` within a `Plot`, the coordinates specified within that `Inset` match those of the plot's axis and scale:

```
Plot[y = 2 x, {x, 0, 5}, Epilog -> Inset["Text", {3, 3}]]
```

[image: Plot Epilog Inset]

Note that "Text" is placed at x=3, y=3. Different thing happens for when `Inset` is used within `LogPlot`:

```
LogPlot[y = x^x, {x, 0, 5}, Epilog -> Inset["Text", {3, 3}]]
```

[image: LogPlot Epilog Inset]

The coordinates are still (3,3) but "Text" is positioned at what appears to be (3,20) with respect to the on-axis coordinates.

What is it about and how do I counter it?

Thanks in advance,
r.

Comment: True. This is because `Log[20.]=2.99573227355399` You can either use `Inset["Text", {3, Log[3]}]`  or I think using Scaled[] is better. I do not know of a way myself to have the scaling of outer coordinates be automatically reflected in the Epilog. You have to do it your self or using Scaled[]

Comment: Sweet and simple. Thanks, Nasser!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just to get an answer on record so the question can be removed from not-answered list.

As Nasser remarked in his comment

> This is because `Log[20.] = 2.99573227355399` You can either use `Inset["Text", {3, Log[3]}]` or I think using `Scaled[]` is better. I do not know of a way myself to have the scaling of outer coordinates be automatically reflected in the Epilog. You have to do it your self or using `Scaled[]`.