# How can I insert text into a relative position in a plot?

Tags: plotting

I use the following code to draw a parametric plot, with `Epilog` to add a point, and text using `Graphics`.

```
graf7 = ParametricPlot[  { delta18[t], delta2D[t]}, {t, 0, 800},
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], 
     Point[{ delta18[0] , delta2D[0]} ], 
     Line[{{20, 160}, {-50, -400}}] } ,
   AspectRatio -> 1, PlotLabel -> "d18O vs dD (g/kgda)",
   PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium
   ];

Show[graf7,
  Graphics[Text["Dot is at surface", {-10.6, -89.4}]],
  Graphics[Text["Black line is MWL ", {-10.6, -89.6}]]  ]
```

For now, it works fine. I experimented with the equations that find the original arguments, `delta18[t]` and `delta2D[t]`, so their value ranges change drastically, and the inserted text is no longer in the plot region.

How can I make the text appear at a *relative* position within the plot, so it is never outside the plot region?

Comment: Related: [Specifying coordinates for Inset on a LogPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36753/121)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must use [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Scaled.html) coordinates to position the text.

Example:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, max},
  PlotRange -> 1.1 {-1, 1},
  Epilog -> {Text["sine", Scaled[{.2, .8}]]}],
 {max, 1, 20}
 ]
```