# How does epilog position work in logplots?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to use [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) in my plots but the way that `Epilog` uses coordinate positions isn't making sense to me. As a minimal example consider,

```
LogPlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, π}, Epilog -> {Text["x", {π/2, 0.2}]}]
```

I'd have expected this to put an "x" in the center of the graph but instead it shows up in the corner:

[image]

I've also tried [`ListLogplot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogPlot.html) and other graphics but they all produce similar results.

**How do I force `Epilog` to use the same positions as the plot?**

Note: I'm using Mathematica V10 on Linux.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36753/specifying-coordinates-for-inset-on-a-logplot

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As shown by the graphic, the `Log` is applied on the *y-axis*, thus you need to apply `Log` to the *y coordinate* of your point:

```
LogPlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, π}, Epilog -> {Text["x", {π/2, Log@0.2}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For completeness purposes [as suggested by rcollyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54909/how-does-epilog-position-work-in-logplots/54910?noredirect=1#comment157840_54910):

```
LogLinearPlot[Tanh[x], {x, 1, 100}, Epilog -> {Text["x", {Log@10, 0.98}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
LogLogPlot[
  Sum[i/(x^2 - 2 i 0.99 x + i^2), {i, {1, 10, 100}}], {x, 0.1, 1000}, 
  Epilog -> {Text["x", Log@{10, 10}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ah, I guess I should have tried that. Perfect, thanks!

Comment: @JeffDror We all faced the same issue ;o) And for `LogLogPlot` it has to be applied to both coordinates of course :)

Comment: @Öskå for completeness, would you post examples with `LogLinearPlot` and `LogLogPlot`, too?