# Background graphics to indicate the experimental values

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a set of data points and I used `ListPlot` to plot the result, now I want to add some graphics in order to show its relevance with observational data. I want to add some colored region and lines in order to show the range of the observational data. It is showing an error of `ListLogLinearPlot: Options expected (instead of -------) beyond position 1 etc`

```
data2 = Import["C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\File\\Plot.xlsx"]
{{{1., 0.00145571}, {2., 0.000512172}, {3., 0.000413558}, {4., 
0.000327206}, {5., 0.000232578}, {6., 0.000222551}, {7., 
0.00021316}, {8., 0.000170132}, {9., 0.000154532}, {10., 
0.000144734}, {11., 0.000142964}, {12., 0.000142123}, {13., 
0.00015819}, {14., 0.000151158}, {15., 0.00014666}, {16., 
0.000156776}, {17., 0.000169387}, {18., 0.000171444}, {19., 
0.000178187}, {20., 0.000205979}, {21., 0.000236261}, {22., 
0.000277336}, {23., 0.000318483}, {24., 0.000306874}, {25., 
0.000305332}, {26., 0.000304559}, {27., 0.00031249}, {28., 
0.00034653}, {29., 0.000357357}, {30., 0.000361888}, {31., 
0.000366362}, {32., 0.000364678}, {33., 0.000351303}, {34., 
0.000383127}, {35., 0.000665384}, {36., 0.000731365}, {37., 
0.000802051}, {38., 0.000822485}, {39., 0.000848101}, {40., 
0.000868197}, {41., 0.000950965}, {42., 0.00105685}, {43., 
0.00118864}, {44., 0.00121142}, {45., 0.00120132}, {46., 
0.00121224}, {47., 0.00119165}, {48., 0.00122794}, {49., 
0.00130161}, {50., 0.00133704}}}

ListLogLinearPlot[data2, AxesLabel -> {Q, r}, LabelStyle -> {Black, 13}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
PlotRange -> {Full, {0, 0.14}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thin], Transparent, Rectangle[{5, 0}, {30, 0.12}]}],
Epilog -> {Thick, Black, Dashed, Line[{{1, 0.12}, {50, 0.12}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Look up `Show`. You can't simply put your Graphics statement inside the arguments of a plotting command.

Comment: You have an evident problem between `PlotMarkers` and `Epilog`. The `Graphics` can be inserted in plotter just as part of `Epilog` or `Prolog`. Or you should use the separate layer of `Graphics` and combine it with `ListLogLinearPlot` using `Show`.

Comment: @Rom38 Is this the right thing?  

`p2 = ListLogLinearPlot[data2, AxesLabel -> {Q, r}, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, 13}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {Full, {0, 0.14}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, 
  Epilog -> {Thick, Black, Dashed, Line[{{1, 0}, {30, 0.12}}]}]`

`Show[p2, Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thin], Transparent, 
   Rectangle[{5, 0}, {30, 0.12}]}]]`

Comment: Looks correct. If this works, I think the question can be closed.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I have added the plot above, it doesn't look right. There is no rectanglular region behind and the dashed line is not horizontal and not in the correct position, it should be on the $r=0.12$ line.

Comment: I see that the rectangle doesn't show up, but the line renders correctly for me. I know of a related issue, it has to do with the behavior of coordinates in Log-plots, let me look up the relevant question.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36753/26956 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54909/26956 and linked questions therein. I find this behavior undesirable, counterintuitive and borderline a bug, but that's the way it is. Please note, that the code for your `Line` in your comment is different from the code in the OP, that's why it's not horizontal. The solution for your case is `Show[p2, Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thin], Transparent, 
   Rectangle[{Log@5, 0}, {Log@30, 0.12}]}]]`. VTC as a duplicate of those.

Comment: also note that your `p2 = ListLogLinearPlot[...] Show[p2, Graphics[...]]` is implicitly multiplying `ListLogLinearPlot[...]` by `Show[...]`, that's why you're getting an undesired, but unrelated error message. Make sure you separate those statements with a newline or a semicolon `;`. Finally, +1 for a clear and concise question.

Comment: @mathemania, Your plot looks bad due to wrong definitions of the `PlotRange`. Look onto your data - the maximum is **0.0014** but you PlotRange is up to **0.14**. Let's correct your misprints and look at the figure again..

Comment: @Rom38 That's not a mistake, the experimental bound is 0.14 but it just so happened that in this model that I'm doing the y values are low. So does the `PlotRange` really matter whether the code `Epilog` will work or not?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP The rectangle already appeared but it seems that the rectangle is overlapping my data, what should I do to place my data in front and the rectangle behind?

Comment: I would do something like `Prolog -> {Transparent, EdgeForm[Directive[Black, Thin]], Rectangle[...]}` as an option passed to `ListLogLinearPlot` (instead of `Show` and `Graphics`, of course).

Comment: @mathemania, `PlotRange` changes the "window" of the figure. In particular, this example shows that your basic layer shows mostly an empty space. Just change the `PlotRange` to appropriate one and you will see the result..
Show[p2,Graphics[...]] should work

Comment: @Rom38 I found the mistake what is causing the dashed line to be diagonal, in my code `Epilog` the y input values are 0 and 0.12, but it should be the same 0.12 for both x values that I want to set the boundary with. So the trend is to start from 0 then rise to 0.12 instead of 0.12 all the way.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Using `Prolog` in `ListLogLinearPlot` worked instead of `Graphics` and `Show` method. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Sorry for the late additional question, if I want to add another rectangle much larger than the one we have now such that the largest rectangle is at the back then the smaller width rectangle is in front of it, then the data is overlapping the two of them, should I just add another `Rectangle`?
`Prolog -> {{LightBlue,Yellow},Rectangle[{Log@1, 0}, {Log@40, 0.12}], Rectangle[{Log@5, 0}, {Log@30, 0.12}]}` This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have a problem with syntax, a *list* of `{LightBlue, Yellow}` is meaningless, you can't have "list-colored" `Rectangle`s. look up the proper usage of `Directive` (its and the `Graphics` pages are relevant).